# sed + string appended on the last line instead on new line

Tags: csv, sed

We have the following csv file

```
more file.csv

ams-site       ,host.aggregator.ttl                ,86400
capacity-scheduler,maximum-am-resource,0.6
yarn-site,yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds,800
```

we need to remove the empty lines from the csv file and also delete the spaces in scv files

so we did the following

```
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' file.csv
sed -i -E 's/(^|,)[[:blank:]]+/\1/g; s/[[:blank:]]+(,|$)/\1/g'  file.csv
```

after above setting by sed

we append new line as

`echo zoo.cfg,timeout,100>> file.cs`

but we see now that `file.csv` looks like this

```
ams-site       ,host.aggregator.ttl                ,86400
capacity-scheduler,maximum-am-resource,0.6
yarn-site,yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds,800zoo.cfg,timeout,100
```

so I suspect with my sed syntax as `sed -i -E 's/(^|,)[[:blank:]]+/\1/g; s/[[:blank:]]+(,|$)/\1/g'`

this bug is looks like carriage return after the last line instead to be on new line

any idea what is wrong in my sed syntax?

Comment: Consider `echo '' >> file.cs` before your echo... because I am thinking the CSV is missing a [newline at end of file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E '/^$/d;s/[[:space:]]+//g' file.cs
```

Enable regular expression interpretation with -E and -R, first delete any blank lines and then substitute one or more spaces for nothing